# How to use Discord Permission on Create Embed Command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, embed, replit

How can I use this?

```
if (not ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages):
    await ctx.send("Please ask a Supporter")
    return
```

for this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def cembed(ctx):
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send('Title?', delete_after=5)
    title = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
  
    await ctx.send('Description?', delete_after=5)
    desc = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)

    embed = discord.Embed(title=title.content, description=desc.content, color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255,0,0))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I already used the permission code once in a muting command but I am not sure where I need to put it in this code if you answer this please explain why I need to put it there.

Comment: maybe first put any place in function and see how it works. And if you get error message then put it in question (not in comments)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

like that:

```
@bot.command()
async def cembed(ctx):
   if (not ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages):
    await ctx.send("Please ask a Supporter")
    return
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send('Title?', delete_after=5)
    title = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
  
    await ctx.send('Description?', delete_after=5)
    desc = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)

    embed = discord.Embed(title=title.content, description=desc.content, color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255,0,0))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```